# Display a block conditionally based on user input button

Tags: shortcode, block-editor, conditional-content

I am looking to put 2 donation forms on a page using a shortcode (or block) and I want them displayed based on currency selected by user,
So for instance a user comes onto the page he will see 2 buttons, One showing "currency A" and one showing "currency B".
If the user selects "Currency A" I want block A displayed and if they choose "Currency B I want block B displayed.
How can I achieve that? (I imagine through JS but is there a simple snippet that can achieve that for me?)

Answer (score 1):

I think the most simple approach (if you're able to add some JS) is to use custom classes for your buttons and blocks that can be settled through advanced settings in block editor. Then a really basic JS snippet can do the trick.

Here's an example in vanilla JS with an [IFFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Glossary/IIFE) that takes care of waiting for DOM to be loaded : https://codepen.io/liqueurdetoile/pen/dyjEYEP

Obviously class names have to be chosen wisely to avoid any trouble.

**EDIT** - You can also use any accordion block for Gutenberg to achieve a similar result. There's plenty available as plugins.

Comment: Thank you, definitely seems like a simple and proper way to go, but I am not familiar with js... Will probably just hire someone on fiverr or another freelance website.

Comment: OK/ Thought you did know JS. You can also achieve your goal with any accordion block. There's plenty available as plugins.